# How to fix Ramda drop dropLast type error in pipe?

Tags: javascript, typescript, pipe, ramda.js, drop

I am using below code using ramda in typescript and it keeps showing error that type is not matching:

```
R.pipe(R.drop(2), R.dropLast(5))("hello world");
```

> TS2769: No overload matches this call.   The last overload gave the following error.     Argument of type '{ (xs: string): string; (xs: readonly unknown[]): unknown[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(x0: readonly unknown[], x1: unknown, x2: unknown) => string'.       Types of parameters 'xs' and 'x0' are incompatible.         Type 'readonly unknown[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.

How should fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the type inference needs a bit of extra help to let it know that you want the type narrowed to a `string`.

e.g.

```
R.pipe<string, string, string>(R.drop(2), R.dropLast(5))("hello world")
// or
R.pipe(R.drop(2) as (str: string) => string, R.dropLast(5))("hello world")
```

Comment: It's strange, why do we need to do this? why typescript can't figure it out?

Comment: I suspect it is the combination of the various possible type signatures of `pipe` combined with the `drop` functions that can take either a list or a string. For example, `R.drop(2, R.dropLast(5, "hello world"))` type-checks with no errors.